# How to fix "send action after loading, problem with loop"

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send data Action from my dashboard page `this.props.dataActions.addChild(this.props.user.children.data[0])`.

But I have a problem with a loop. I don't know what to do in this case. Please check my code below:

I tried to add loading to `componentDidUpdate` but it's not helped.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    // 
    console.log(this.state.loading)
    if (this.props.user && this.props.user.children && this.props.user.children.data) {
      console.log('iiiii', this.props.user.children.data[0])
      this.props.dataActions.addChild(this.props.user.children.data[0])
      if (!this.state.loading) {
        this.setState({ selectedChildren: this.props.user.children.data[0] })
      }

    }
  }
```

Please check screenshot:

What is the best way to stop the loop and send `this.props.dataActions.addChild` just one time

https://ibb.co/rm18W1b

Dashboard index code: 
https://pastebin.com/5V2ceAHK

Answer (score 0):

1- it's not good to use setState in Update lifecycle functions like componentWillUpdate, componentDidUpdate. that can cause the loop you are getting.

2- if you want to run this action once then use componentWillMount if you need this to run on some event then make a function and call it when triggered by click or any event.

3- updating props can cause loop with componentWillRecieveProps. and the setting state can cause a loop with componentWillUpdate, componentDidUpdate.

4- you can divide your code into more components that may help you manage the states.

review your states and props again with the lifecycle will help you to find the way you need. I cannot give the exact solution by knowing the scenario, but the issues that are causing it.

Comment: I understand, but with componentWillMount I can't see my props(it's empty)
I need to send  `this.props.dataActions.addChild(this.props.user.children.data[0])` on page load
And I need to get back reducer `selectedChildren: {}` (but object with first child

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use `setState` inside didUpdate life cycle. However, if you have no choice regarding the life cycle method, you have to be very careful about the condition by which you set your state

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    // 
    console.log(this.state.loading)
    if (this.props.user && this.props.user.children && this.props.user.children.data) {
      console.log('iiiii', this.props.user.children.data[0])
      this.props.dataActions.addChild(this.props.user.children.data[0])
      if (
        !this.state.loading &&
        this.state.selectedChildren !== this.props.user.children.data[0] // see this line here ??
      ) {
        this.setState({ selectedChildren: this.props.user.children.data[0] })
      }

    }
  }
```

In the code above , you should check if the selectedChildren is not already what you have in your state

```
this.state.selectedChildren !== this.props.user.children.data[0]
```

If this `selectedChildren` is an object, you have to use object comparison modules, either custom made or from vendor packages. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) for more information regarding object equality

EDIT:
In your code

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    //

    if (
      this.props.user && 
      this.props.user.children && 
      this.props.user.children.data &&
      checkIf_prevProps.child isNotEqualTo this.props.user.children.data[0]
    ) {
      console.log('iiiii', this.props.user.children.data[0])
      this.props.dataActions.addChild(this.props.user.children.data[0])
    }
  }
```

So check if `checkIf_prevProps.child isNotEqualTo this.props.user.children.data[0]`. Or simply check for any entry in your state variable that way you know that the state has already been updated.
But keep in mind that this is a dirty hack sort of thing to protect infinite rendering.

Comment: I don't need to use `setState`. I need to send this code to action
`his.props.dataActions.addChild(this.props.user.children.data[0])`
but I have problem with loop.

Do you have some idea how to send this code without loop

Comment: @BorisCivcic where exactly is this `loop` you are talking about ?

Comment: Please check the screenshot. 
https://ibb.co/rm18W1b
SelectedChildren needs to have just one array. But I have 52 there

Comment: @BorisCivcic edited my answer, I hope it answers your query

Comment: Sorry...but it's same

Comment: I resolved on this way

`
setTimeout(() => {
      if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.state.userDates).length === 0) {
      }
      else {
        if (this.props.user && this.props.user.children && this.props.user.children.data) {
          this.props.dataActions.addChild(this.props.user.children.data[0])
        }
      }
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    }, 2500);
`